# How to create G matrix in Raptor code?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, codec, forwarderrorcorrection

I already finished make G matrix in LT code and and want to make G matrix in Raptor code. I read that Raptor code that combines between LDPC and LT code. So, the matrix of Raptor code is same LT code.It is only different the distribution-(the LT is RSD and Raptor is shokrollahi. Is it correct? Do you implement it in the matlab or C? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still interested, but here it goes:

First of all, which Raptor code you're talking about? R10 (RFC 5053) or RaptorQ (RFC 6330)?

You've got the basic idea right, but the matrix is not exactly the same. If you look at the RFC (any of them) you'll see that there are submatrices apart from the LT one. These submatrices define the constraint relationships and will ensure the very nice properties offered by Raptor codes. The LT submatrix itself, is not the same as a LT code matrix because, as you said, the probability mass function is different (defined via the various generators - e.g., Tuple generator).

As far as implementing goes, it depends on what you want from it. If only want to learn Matlab is definitely the way to go. It will be much easier and you should have a working prototype in no time. If you want to use it in your own software or develop a library for other developers to use, then I would recommend C/C++.

If you're wondering "why you should listen to me": I implemented and maintain a RaptorQ library - [OpenRQ](http://www.lasige.di.fc.ul.pt/openrq) . It is open source, if you're interested in checking it out. It was implemented in Java, and I can't say I'd recommend the experience to anyone. But at the end of the day it works and became a really solid project.

Comment: In my case, I only consider RFC5053 code. My problem is only how to make LDPC matrix combine with LT matrix for raptor code. Do you have any sugession

Comment: Could you please direct me to a place where LT codes or Raptor Codes are implemented in C? A simple C program would do. I couldn't find a source in the internet. Thank you for your time.